# Insert or Updated getting "Transaction query already complete"

Tags: bookshelf.js

How can I correctly search for a row in the database and `INSERT`/`UPDATE` accordingly to the search result (`INSERT` if not found, `UPDATE` if found)?

I'm currently doing this:

```
bookshelf.transaction(async function (t) {
            for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                let row = pmsParser.getRow(x);
                if (_.isEmpty(row)) {
                    break;
                }

                let data = {
                    lastUpdate: moment(row.lastUpdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm').toDate(),
                    mvs: row.version,
                    color: row.color,
                    location: row.location,
                    status: row.status
                };

                new Vehicle({ chassi: row.chassi })
                    .fetch({ require: true })
                    .then(model => {

                        return new Vehicle(model)
                            .save(data, { transacting: t, patch: true });

                    })
                    .catch(Vehicle.NotFoundError, err => {
                        new Vehicle(data)
                            .save('chassi', row.chassi, { transacting: t })
                            .then(() => {
                                console.log(`Inserted... ${row.chassi}`);
                            });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err.message);
                    });
            }
        })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.json({ status: false, count: 0, error: err.message });
            });
```

And I receive this error:

```
Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
Unhandled rejection Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
    at completedError (/home/node/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:297:9)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:266:22
    at tryCatcher (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
    at Client_SQLite3.trxClient.query (/home/node/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:264:34)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:138:36)
    at Runner.tryCatcher (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Runner.query (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:15:34)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:61:21
    at tryCatcher (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/using.js:185:26
    at tryCatcher (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/node/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
```

Knex debug output

```
  knex:tx trx1: Starting top level transaction +0ms
  knex:tx trx1: releasing connection +28ms
  knex:tx undefined: Transaction completed: update "vehicles" set "color" = ?, "lastUpdate" = ?, "location" = ?, "mvs" = ?, "status" = ? where "id" = ? +15ms
Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
  knex:tx undefined: Transaction completed: update "vehicles" set "color" = ?, "lastUpdate" = ?, "location" = ?, "mvs" = ?, "status" = ? where "id" = ? +8ms
Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
```

Comment: have you tried setting the environment variable as stated: `export DEBUG=knex:tx`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When under a transaction *ALL* related database accesses must be within the context of the transaction.

```
//...
new Vehicle({ chassi: row.chassi })
    .fetch({ require: true, transacting: t })
    .then(model => {
//...
```

Your iterations are not being correctly promisified. That makes your changes to escape the transaction context, causing the 'Transaction query already complete' error. When creating promises within a loop it is always advisable to collect them and submit to a promise collection handling, such as `Promise.all()`. This will avoid escaping the transaction context before all promises are resolved.

Those changes may lead to a code as below (*untested*):

```
bookshelf.transaction(async function (t) {
  let promises = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    let row = pmsParser.getRow(x);
    if (_.isEmpty(row)) {
      break;
    }
    let data = {
      lastUpdate: moment(row.lastUpdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:mm').toDate(),
      mvs: row.version,
      color: row.color,
      location: row.location,
      status: row.status
    };
    promises.push(
      new Vehicle({ chassi: row.chassi })
        .fetch({ require: true, transacting: t })
        .then(model => {
          return model // no need to use 'new Vehicle()' here
            .save(data, { transacting: t, patch: true });
        })
        .catch(Vehicle.NotFoundError, err => {
          return new Vehicle(data) // missing 'return'
            .save('chassi', row.chassi, { transacting: t })
            .then(() => {
               console.log(`Inserted... ${row.chassi}`);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
          // throw err; // should rethrow it!
        })
    );
  }
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .catch(function (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return res.json({ status: false, count: 0, error: err.message });
    });
};
```

Comment: The loop is to import a CSV file with 20K rows. Will it be problem if I add 20K promises to the collection and run all of them at once?

Comment: When in dev environment I'm using SQLite and even if I remove the transaction, after a few hundred rows INSERTed/UPDATEd correctly, it gets `Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full`.

Comment: `Promise.all()` only ensures all promises have been resolved. In fact when you call `Promise.all()` with 20K updates it is very probable that most of them are already resolved. And, if your transactions usually consist of 20K updates, you may have to tune your database.

Comment: This pool error is a sign you have database operations outside of the transaction. Every transactional operation *MUST* happen within the same connection in order to ensure ACIDness. This is a one more point for ensuring your `fetch()` calls include the `transacting: t` option.